# Можно ли в данных предложениях рассматривать части, отделенные/выделенные тире, как уточняющие члены предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

1) Призывал Усачева Ставропольский горвоенкомат — меньше чем через две недели после освобождения столицы Ставрополья от фашистов.

2) После госпиталя он двинулся дальше военными дорогами — Гомель, Бобруйск, Барановичи, государственная граница СССР, Польша, освобождение Варшавы, бои в Восточной Пруссии.

3) Те, благодаря кому мы живем сегодня, остаются с нами рядом — до тех пор, пока мы их помним.

4) А вот второй синдром — "путешественничества" — скорее глобальный.

Answer (score 1):

Уточняющие члены по отношению к уточняемым служат наименованиями более конкретными по значению, так как они сужают понятие, передаваемое уточняемым (основным) членом предложения, или в каком-либо плане ограничивают его. Таким образом, члены уточняемый и уточняющий соотносятся как общее и частное, широкое и конкретное, родовое и видовое, причём уточняющий член предложения следует за уточняемым (а не наоборот!).
https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html

Уточняющие члены предложения уточняют (поясняют) предшествующее слово, от которого можно поставить к ним вопрос:
*2) После госпиталя он двинулся дальше военными дорогами (какими именно дорогами?) — Гомель, Бобруйск, Барановичи, государственная граница СССР, Польша, освобождение Варшавы, бои в Восточной Пруссии.

4) А вот второй синдром (какой именно синдром?) — "путешественничества" — скорее глобальный.*

В первом примере не от чего поставить вопрос. А в третьем обстоятельства места и времени не соотносятся. Тире в них интонационное. Этот вид тире очень популярен, даже у некоторых писателей-классиков:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=197